# custom button always too big

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

I am trying to create a custom button with its shape being as similar as possible to the one of the Android default button. The problem is, no matter how much I reduce the height, it doesn't go below a certain value:

image of custom and default button

[image]

The text size of both buttons is 14sp. Here the xlm-code for my custom button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorBtnActive" />

    <corners android:radius="2dp" />

    <size
        android:height="16dp"/>

</shape>
```

So even if I write `<size android:height="50dp"/>`, the button looks the same.

Here part of the xlm-file of the activity:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector_selected"
    android:text="custom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="default"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501" />
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

**EDIT:** 
So upon your suggestions I removed the size-tag.Sadly, the button still looks the same. However, I noticed that the buttoms have the same size, the default button just looks smaller: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyF2H.png)

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: Can you try removing size element of xml ? Button always has default padding.

Comment: remove  `<size  android:height="16dp"/>` in your xml . try with regular layout (Linear or relative) instead of constraint .

Comment: Removing the size-tag didn't help... I tried to switch from constraint layout to relative layout, but that messed up everything... Anyways, the button still looked the same.

Comment: @pskink i don't thing padding bigger will work

Comment: yes, i was wrong with padding (padding is for the content), if you want to "inset" your shape then add your `<shape>` tag inside `<inset>` tag, more: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Inset

Comment: @pskink: Thanks, I think that's what I'm looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

when you set any Background to A Button its hight will increase check below test cases

- when you set both button background the button size are same

Try this you also need to set **android:background** to your **default** button like this

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/demo"
        android:text="custom"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="default"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: ![enter image description here]

**without setting custom background to your custom button**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="custom"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="default"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

**EDIT** **Android Button has default padding.**

**check the default Size of button**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/demo"
        android:text="custom"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="default"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: But this will make the default button look like my custom button, right? I want it to be the other way round though...

Comment: You just use my idea .@Prem

Comment: @KeLiuyue no check my updated ans i also mention the reason why its works

Comment: @KeLiuyue if you down votes my ans than its  wrong remove your down vote

Comment: You just add `<size
        android:height="16dp"/>` at the first edit .And when I answer the question .then you change it .

Comment: yup i was just checking in my machine about the same

Comment: Hehe. you do it.

Comment: @KeLiuyue move-ahed this comments are off-toppic

Comment: Okay thank you, the problem seems to be that I am need to change the background tint instead of the background itself...

Comment: @newman yup but not that **background tint** only work on api>21

Answer (score 1):

Android Button has default padding.

When I set `android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"` in the Button.
It will be the same of custom `Button` .

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="default"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501" />
```

**Output**

[image]