# Appcompat button background style

Tags: android, button, styles

I have a button style, but `background`, `colorAccent` and `colorButtonNormal` not working on my button. I tried to change background drawable, and change different colors, and change `style=` to `android:theme=` but in wont help. Here's my style:

```
 <style name="ButtonWithBorder" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/btn_border</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_text_size</item>
</style>
```

My button:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/descriptionReserveButton"
        style="@style/ButtonWithBorder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/reserve_place"
        />
    <Button
```

and my background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_outline" android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_outline" android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_outline"/>
```

I want to style my button once, and rest of time just use this style.How can i accept my style to button

what i need:

[image]

**EDIT**

my mistake was in

`<item name="background">@drawable/btn_border</item>`

it have to be `<item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_border</item>`

new screen

[image]

Comment: Can you show an image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Srijith i edited my question

Comment: So you will have a transparent button with border normally, and when pressed it should show a solid color, right?

Comment: Main color of button have to be primary, and border normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/descriptionReserveButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"        
    style="@style/MyButton"
    android:text="reserve_place" />
```

Style

```
 <style name="MyButton" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
        <item name="android:textColor">#149aed</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#020e39</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edterr</item>

    </style>
```

**@drawable/edterr**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <solid android:color="#030a64" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#149aed" android:dashWidth="5sp">
    </stroke>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: I can do that, and it will work, but i dont want to set padding, and background to all buttons of this type

Comment: @Toper can you exaplain more and no need to set padding

Comment: I want to style my button once, and rest of time just use this style

Comment: @Toper please also specify that in your question

Comment: I have another question, can you help? I now i have a button with backgorund as i want, but the standart button is smaller than button with background. They have the same values, difference - jsut background . i added screen to question. How can i fix that?

Comment: @Toper yes i will help

Comment: @Toper check this my ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/47346492/8112541 it will help you

Answer (score 1):

In you styles.xml create a style for your button with the background:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_round_rect</item>
</style>
```

The drawable shape_round_rect.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="#2c73ca" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="6dp" android:top="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="#2c73ca" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="6dp" android:top="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

And set the style in your button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/descriptionReserveButton"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:text="Reserve Place" />
```